# Is it true for any algebras $A,B,C$ that $(A+B)\cap C = A\cap C+B\cap C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebras

Let $A,B,C$ be subalgebras of some algebra $X$. I've managed to show, that $A\cap C+B\cap C\subseteq (A+B)\cap C$. If $x\in A\cap C+B\cap C$, then $x=a+b$, where $a\in A\cap C, b\in B\cap C$. Since $a,b\in C$ then $a+b=x\in C$. Since $a\in A, b\in B$ then $a+b=x\in (A+B)$, so $x\in (A+B)\cap C$.

Does the reverse inclusion holds? I could neither show it nor disprove it.

Here $A+B$ denotes subalgebra $\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Comment: It's not true in general for vector spaces: take for example, $3$ non-parallel lines through the origin.  If you don't require your algebras to be unital, then this works for algebras, too, since you can just make the vector space an algebra with the trivial multiplication $v \cdot w = 0$.  If you want it to be unital, I'm not sure...